# function wont return result php

Tags: php, function

I have this function:

```
function dulide($uid) {
    global $mysqli, $sm;
    $city = $mysqli->query("SELECT city FROM users WHERE id = '" . $sm['user']['id'] . "'");
    $haha = $city->fetch_assoc();
    $citye = $haha['city'];
    $sql = "SELECT id,age,name,email,city,fixed FROM users WHERE fixed=1 AND city = '" . $citye . "' LIMIT 5";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($user = $query->fetch_object()) {
            $return .= '<tr><td> ' . $user->name . ' </td></tr><tr><td>';
            $uid = $user->id;
            $photos = $mysqli->query("SELECT photo FROM users_photos WHERE approved = 1 and profile = 1 and u_id = '" . $uid . "' order by id desc LIMIT 1");
            if ($photos->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($up = $photos->fetch_object()) {

                    $return .= '<img src="' . $up->photo . '" alt="Smiley face" height="50" width="50">';
                }
            }
            $return .= ' </td></tr> ';
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

When I try to call the function with

```
<?=dulide($uid); ?>
```

Nothing happens. Do anyone have a solution for this?

Huge amount of charma and blessings is given out! :)

Thanks on behalf

Comment: You need to debug this yourself. Step by step

Comment: Im not sure at this point but how about using `echo $return` instead of `return $return`?
The `return` statement will just return the value of `$return` but is not made to display data.

Comment: yes, but when i call the function at <?=dulide($uid);?> i guess it echo the function? So no need to write echo in the function? right?

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) and [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param).

Answer (score 0):

So turns out there was a database fault that made my function not work..Thanks for your help, another time would be good to make }else{ after num rows to post if no result :)